# Ingresar valores dentro de Variable python

Tags: python, selenium, while, get

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding=utf-8
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import xlsxwriter
from Data_tags import Inventory_data

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Martin/Desktop/chromedriver')


def run(d):
    login("Usuario", "pass")
    NewTag("https://platform/en/users/inventory/create")
    Device = str(d.get("Li_platform")) #Mobile Web 
    Inicio_Li_Platform = ('//*[@id="platform_listbox"]/li[')
    Final_Li_Platform = (']')
    Platform(Inicio_Li_Platform+""+Device+""+Final_Li_Platform)
    NameTag(d.get("TagName"))
    Floor_Rate(d.get("Floor_price"))
    Save_Tag('save')
    Save_xlsx(d.get("Excel_name"))
    Inicio_Li_Publisher = ('//*[@id="publisher_listbox"]/li[')
    Final_Li_Publisher = (']')
    Publisher = str(d.get("Li_Publisher")) #Publisher Altitude
    Publisher_Li(Inicio_Li_Publisher+""+Publisher+""+Final_Li_Publisher)
    Tag_Rate_and_Save(d.get("Tag_Rate"))
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.close()

def main():
    while True:
        tag = input("Ingrese la clave deseada, nada para salir: ")
        if not tag:
            break  
        d = (Inventory_data.get("Inventario_datos")).get(tag, None)
        if d:
            run(d)
        else:
            print("Clave no encontrada.")

main()
```

Esto es una parte de mi codigo con el cual puedo ingresar a traves de la terminal un valor el cual me sirve para ejecutar mi programa. Dicho valor queda en mi variable (`d = (Inventory_data.get("Inventario_datos")).get(tag, None)`).
Hasta aca el programa corre perfecto, pero necesito ingresar mas de un valor a la vez. Cada vez que introduzco un valor el programa corre, lo que estoy buscando es que el programa se ejecute por cada valor que introduzco en una unica vez.
Un ejemplo para ser mas claro seria escribir en la terminal "auto", "camioneta", "bicicleta" y que el programa ejecute todas las funciones para auto, una vez que termine con auto, haga lo mismo con camioneta y asi sucesivamente con todos los demas valores.

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes capturar una sola cadena separando cada key por un separador adecuado como una coma o cualquier carácter que no este permitido en las propias keys. Luego aplicas `str.split` para separar cada key y usarla para ejecutar la función por:

```
def main():
    tags = input("Ingrese las claves deseadas separadas por comas: ")

    for tag in (tag.strip() for tag in tags.split(",")):
        d = (Inventory_data.get("Inventario_datos")).get(tag, None)
        if d:
            run(d)
        else:
            print('Error: Clave "{}" no encontrada.'.format(tag))
```

La entrada debe ser algo así:

> auto, camioneta, bicicleta, camion

**Edición:**

En Python 2.x hay que cambiar `input` por `raw_input`:

```
tags = raw_input("Ingrese las claves deseadas separadas por comas: ")
```

Comment: Me responde ese error...AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'. Aunque solo me pasa cuando introduzco los dos valores, si coloco uno corre bien. Como podria hacer?

Comment: Que introduces exactamente cuando falla? he probado el código y funciona perfectamente en Python 3

Comment: USo Python 2.7. Introduzco “Alti MW $ 3 |”,  “Alti MW $ 3 |”. Vale aclarar que tomo los datos de mi dic

Comment: Cambia `input` por `raw_input` y no se introducen las comillas. Serian `Alti MW $ 3 |,  Alti MW $ 3 |`

Comment: Recuerda siempre agregar la etiqueta `python-2.7` a tus preguntas si usas esta versión de Python. Hay diferencias significativas entre Python 3 y Python 2 e influye en las posibles respuestas. Por otro lado, si tu aplicación va a tener una vida larga considera no usar Python 2, no va a tener actualizaciones importantes y dejara de tener soporte en 2020. Un saludo.

Comment: Ya esta, tenia que cambiar el la funcion del login y la de cerrar el driver de lugar, dentro de el main! Muchas gracias!

Comment: Tengo un  limite de cantidad los cuales puedo ingresar. No puedo mas de 54. Sabes como aumentarlo??? Me refiero a 54 parecidos de Alti MW $3 |.